# Analysing output characters as vowels, punctuation etc

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char string[20];
    int len = strlen(string);

    //Asking the User to input some characters to use in the program
    printf("Enter a few characters please:\n");
    scanf("%s", string);

    //For loop to print each character of the string on a new line
    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
    {
    printf("%c\n", string[i]);
    }

    //Test print to check the contents of the string
    printf("string's contents: '%s'\n", string);

    return 0;
}
```

This the code I currently have it asks the user for an input of characters, now I want to be able to analyse each character that is output to determine whether it is a vowel, repeated character or punctuation. for example if the user inputs 'AfsdhheE'

the program should output:

A - upper case vowel
f
s
d
h
h - duplicate character
e - lower case vowel
E - upper case vowel

Thanks in advance for your help.

```
// If statement to check whether the character is an upper case vowel
if (ch == 'A' || ch == 'E' || ch == 'I' || ch == 'O' || ch == 'U')
    printf("%c is an upper case vowel.\n", ch);

// If statement to check whether the character is a lower case vowel
if (ch == 'a' || ch == 'e' || ch == 'i' || ch == 'o' || ch == 'u')
    printf("%c is a lower case vowel.\n", ch);
```

This is what I thought might work for vowels, but I'm unsure of how to implement it into the loop.

But for punctuation and duplicate characters I haven't been able to come up with a way to do it.

Comment: Show what you have tried and show the expected output for a given input.

Comment: `int len = strlen(string);` should be after `scanf("%s", string);`.

Answer (score 0):

For punctuation, check out the function ispunct(). For more info on that, see http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_ispunct.htm.

For vowels, here is a good example of how to go about it: http://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/58821-isvowel-included-ctype-c-lang.html.

Repeated characters are only slightly more complicated. If this were C++, I would use a map to keep track of characters already found in the array. In C, you could keep an array of unique characters to compare against.